# C: linked list segfaults. while conditon fail to evaulate to check for NULL

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to check a linked list for duplicate values in a list but for some reason I keep getting a segfault.

This is the function I wrote to check for duplicate numbers:

```
void        dup_checker(t_stack *stack, int value)
{
    int counter;

    counter = 0;
    while (stack)
    {
        if ((stack->elem == value) && (counter < 3))
            counter++;
        if (counter == 2)
            error_msg();
        stack = stack->next;
    }
}
```

The program fails at this line:

```
if ((stack->elem == value) && (counter < 3))
```

The while loop in my dup_checker fails to pick up a NULL pointer. I even used and if statement to check but still fails. The if statement:

```
if (stack != NULL)
```

This is my function to push a new value to the stack:

```
void    push(t_stack **curr, const char *elem)
{
    t_stack         *new;
    int             value;

    digit_checker(elem);
    value = ft_atoi(elem);
    if (!(new = (t_stack *)malloc(sizeof(t_stack))))
        return ;
    new->elem = value;
    new->next = (*curr);
    new->index = 1;
    (*curr) = new;
    dup_checker((*curr), value);
}
```

This is my main function:

```
int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_stack *stack_a;
    t_stack *stack_b;

    if (ac > 1)
    {
        ac--;
        stack_b = NULL;
        while (ac > 0)
            push(&stack_a, av[ac--]);
        //normalizer(&stack_a);
        //check_args(&stack_a, &stack_b);
        //is_sorted(stack_a, stack_b);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I used a debugger and this is the result I got:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555a96 in dup_checker (stack=0xe48348e289485ed1, value=2) at sorter.c:57
57          if ((stack->elem == value) && (counter < 3))
```

I also used valgrind to find the issue but with no success.

I previously wrote this code on a MAC machine and it worked with no problems, but I am now using Ubuntu and have this issue. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you actually printed out `stack` at that point to see whether it really is NULL (I doubt it)?

Comment: `t_stack *stack_a;` ==> `t_stack *stack_a = NULL;` There is no determinate value in `stack_a`. Thus, in your push the initial node insertion performing `new->next = (*curr);` is saving an indeterminate value as the tail pointer of your stack.

Comment: @WhozCraig THANKS SO MUCH!! that fixed it. I didn't realize I still had to initialize the stack to NULL even though I'm initializing it with a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
t_stack *stack_a;

if (ac > 1)
{
    ac--;
    while (ac > 0)
        push(&stack_a, av[ac--]);
```

The variable pointer: `stack_a` has not been initialized, so contains what ever trash is on the program stack at that location.  To fix, suggest replacing:

```
t_stack *stack_a;
```

with

```
t_stack *stack_a = NULL;
```